# Looking to make an static member reference immutable, not a reference to a immutable object

Tags: c++

For reasons (mostly around the idea of mock-ability), we have this abstract interface idea...

```
struct BundleOfInterfaces
{
   static Interface1& interface1;
   static Interface2& interface2;
   ...
};
```

So we access the functions in the interfaces via  `BundleOfInterfaces::interface1.function1(...)`

How can I make the references immutable so nobody can do `BundleOfInterfaces::interface1 = MyNewInterface1;`?

Placing `const` on it seems to make the reference to a const object, which forces the referenced implementations to have all their methods be const (and prevents internal states).

I know I can hide it behind a getter function and make the actual reference private, but I assume there's some way I can do this with `const`, but it doesn't seem to matter where the `const` gets placed.

Comment: The reference is already immutable.  `InterfacesBundle::interface1 = MyNewInterface1;` does not change the reference.  It changes the value of the thing the reference refers to.  If you don't want the thing being refered to to be changed, then that needs to be `const`.

Comment: or `Interface1::operator=() = delete;` but that still is not an issue of the reference but of the interface

Comment: Ah, thanks all, especially @NathanOliver.   The test code I wrote was allowing the assignment to compile, but I didn't actually test to see if it changed which interface was being referenced.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number also thanks for your comment.  Adding the deleted assignment operator prevents the assignment from compiling, preemptively dealing with the potential confusion.

Comment: References cannot be "retargeted" to refer to another object. You can use a pointer if you want to change where it points: `static Interface1 *const interface1;` Writing `const` _after_ the `*` means that the pointer is const, but the actual `Interface1` is not.

Comment: @anatolyg While I appreciate the effort to add duplicates, I don't believe any of the "duplicate" questions actually directly answer the question I have asked.

Comment: I don't think this question should be marked as duplicate, but this is not too important, since you got a good answer. Voted to reopen just because I can.

Comment: @anatolyg sorry, I thought you were the editor that added that. :)  I'm good and learned something today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrapping up what has been said in comments...

The reference is already immutable. You cannot rebind a reference. Memory usage to store the static member aside, the simple image of a reference merely being an alias for the referenced object is appropriate here. You can assign to the reference because you can assign to an instance of `Interface1`. The only way to prevent `BundleOfInterfaces::interface1 = MyNewInterface1;` is to prevent assignment to an instance of `Interface1` in general. This is not actually related to using a reference as static member and can be achieved by deleting the assignment `Interface1::operator=(const Interface1&) = delete;`.